# Dynamic state city drop down list in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have gone half mad trying to figure out what is wrong with my code,so need some help here,
my code works fine ,actually what my code does is it dynamically gets forms 2 dropdownlists ,one for the state and one for the city when i select any state its corresponding cities are populated from the db in the city dropdownlist!,the state dropdownlist is populated with the states but the city dropdownlist  is populated with undefined options!,this is the basic problem i am facing,i am pasting my code also,maybe anyone could figure out what basically is wrong with it!

**HOMEcontroller**

```
public class homeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /home/
    DataClasses1DataContext dd = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        ViewBag.state = dd.tb_statecities.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m.state }).Distinct().ToList();
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult city(string state)
    {

        var v = dd.tb_statecities.Where(m => m.state == state).Select(m => m.city).ToList();
        return Json(v, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }

}
```

**INDEX.CSHTML**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#state').change(function () {

            var val = $('#state').val();
            $.get("home/city", { state: val }, function (data) {
                var v="<option>Select</option>"
                $.each(data, function (i, q) {

                    v += "<Option value=" + q.city + ">" + q.city + "</option>";


                });
                $('#city').html(v);

            });

        });

    });



</script>



<div>
    @Html.DropDownList("state", "Select")
    @Html.DropDownList("city", new List<SelectListItem> {    new SelectListItem{Text="Select",Value="0"}


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that `tb_statecities.city` is a string, so this query here is returning a `List<string>`, not a `List<tb_statecity>`...

```
var v = dd.tb_statecities
            .Where(m => m.state == state)
            .Select(m => m.city)
            .ToList();
```

That means in JavaScript, `q` is already the name of the city, which explains why `q.city` is `undefined`. Try this...

```
$.each(data, function (i, q) {
    v += "<Option value=" + q+ ">" + q + "</option>";
});
```

Comment: Yes problem solved,thanks a lot
but can you please detail me a bit why i was getting this error so that i could avoid it in future,thanks a lot in advance

Comment: In .NET you are selecting the city name (`.Select(m => m.city)`)... so it's returning a list of strings, and that becomes an array of strings in JavaScript.